# What is a sequence of functions that converge weakly in Lp, but not strongly?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading Royden’s real analysis. In his book, a sequence of functions in Lp converges weakly if every bounded linear functional in the dual space converges in R.

Can anyone discuss the importance of weak convergence and give an example of a sequence that converges weakly, but not strongly?

Comment: For example, take an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space and an orthonormal basis $(\phi_k)$. Then $\phi_k$ converges weakly to zero, but not strongly (check the former using Riez).

Comment: I am new this stuff and haven't got to the chapter on Hilbert space yet...

Comment: Do you know the sequence spaces $\mathcal{l}^p$? If yes, $l^2$ is a separable Hilbert space you can work with. If not, I would recommend reading a bit further and then coming back to this.

Comment: Yep, I know about L2. Just not Hilbert space yet. Can give a concrete example of the basis and weak convergence?